# Undo wrong installation of SharePoint 2013 Service Pack

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, service-pack

I installed Service Pack 1 of SharePoint 2013 Foundation instead of Service Pack 1 of SharePoint 2013 server. I have SharePoint 2013 server installed. How can I undo this?

I tried going to Control Panel and running the repair but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the Server Service Pack. When it comes to SharePoint patches, you really can't "go back" (easily).

Comment: was thinking the same but was worried it would cause more issues...

Comment: Nope, you should be set.

Answer (score 2):

their is no easy way as far i know unless uninstall the SharePoint.
I would simply install the SharePoint server SP1, you will all set.

Maybe you Know Server Service Pack include both Foundation & server SP1. So if you installed the foundation separately then when you run the Server SP1 it will automatically detect it and install only server related stuff as foundation already deployed.